# SQL for new distinct users pers day

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

Bit rusty on my SQL and I've spent too long trying to figure this out so thought I'd ask here :)

I'm trying to get the number of distinct NEW users per day visiting my web UI. I have goals on Monthly Active Users and want track how I am getting to this month by month. For example I want to see how many distinct users I had on 16-Jan and compares it with 16-Feb.

My first problem is how to get the number of NEW users per day. I expect to have a higher number on the first day of the month with it decreasing as the month continues.

My SQL is:

```
select day, count(distinct(user)) as distinct_users
from mytable
where year = 2020 and month = 2
group by day
order by day desc
```

But this does not remove duplicated. For example if I visited the website on 2 days and it got logged in `mytable` then I would appear in both days using the SQL above. Ideally I only want to appear in the first day I appear in `mytable`

Consider `mytable` had this

```
day  user
----------
1    richard
1    paul
1    alexis
2    richard
2    david
```

I want the query to return

```
day   cnt
----------
1     3    (richard, paul, alexis)
2     1    (david - no richard as he has already been returned)
```

How can I remove the users that have already appeared?

Thanks

Comment: Distinct is not a function. Remove those redundant parentheses to write clearer code. I.e. simply `count(distinct user) as distinct_users`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the earliest date per user and then aggregate on the earliest date.

```
select t1.day,count(distinct t.user) as cnt
from (select user,min(day) as minday
      from tbl
      group by user
     ) t 
left join tbl t1 on t1.day = t.minday -- to get days with no new users as well
group by day
order by day
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select day, count(*) cnt
from (select min(day) day from mytable group by user) t
group by day
order by day
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afda75ba582cc1cbf0cb7c8a4ec8abac)**:

```
day | cnt
--: | --:
  1 |   3
  2 |   1
```

There is no need to join again the original table in the outer query: this makes the query more expensive, whithout adding significant value.